# fail to post notification on channel "null" more see in Logcat and not even showed action in Oreo

Tags: java, android, notifications

I faced error

> developer warning for package "package name" fail to post
>   notification on channel "null" more see in Logcat

can anyone help me with a normal app that uses TimePicker to set the time ..and also uses intents,etc instead of normal comparisons.This is the code that i've done till now.But this is not working. The 'TimePicker' sets the time and on pressing the 'ToggleButton' a 'TextVew' shows that alarm is on .But when the alarmtime is reached,Alarm Ringing message is not shown.Please someone help me out. this is the code of main activity

AlarmNotificationReceiver

```
package com.example.kishorsinh.yogaapp;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class AlarmNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        Intent in = new Intent(context, ListExercises.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, in, 0);


        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yoga)
                .setContentTitle("It's About Time")
                .setContentText("text.... ")
                .setContentInfo("text....")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
    }



}
```

Setting Page

```
package com.example.kishorsinh.yogaapp;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.example.kishorsinh.yogaapp.Database.YogaDB;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class SettingPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSave;
    RadioButton rdiEasy,rdiMedium,rdiHard;
    RadioGroup rdiGroup;
    YogaDB yogaDB;
    ToggleButton switchAlarm;
    TimePicker timePicker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting_page);

        //init view
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        rdiGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdiogroup);
        rdiEasy = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdioEasy);
        rdiMedium = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdioMedium);
        rdiHard = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdioHard);

        switchAlarm = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.switchAlarm);
        timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        yogaDB = new YogaDB(this);

        int mode = yogaDB.getSettingMode();
        setRadioButton(mode);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveWorkoutMode();
                saveAlarm(switchAlarm.isChecked());
                Toast.makeText(SettingPage.this, "Saved!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    private void saveAlarm(boolean checked) {
        if(checked)
        {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent;
            PendingIntent pendingIntent;

            intent = new Intent(SettingPage.this,AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);

            //Set time for alarm
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date toDay = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ) {
                //new version mate
                calendar.set(toDay.getYear(), toDay.getMonth(), toDay.getDate(), timePicker.getHour(), timePicker.getMinute());

                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

                Log.d("DEBUG", "Alarm will wake at" + timePicker.getHour() + ":" + timePicker.getMinute());
            }
            else
            {
                //olderversion mate
                calendar.set(toDay.getYear(), toDay.getMonth(), toDay.getDate(), timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

                Log.d("DEBUG", "Alarm will wake at" + timePicker.getCurrentHour() + ":" + timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //Cancel Alarm
            Intent intent = new Intent(SettingPage.this,AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    }

    private void saveWorkoutMode() {
        int selectedID = rdiGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        if(selectedID == rdiEasy.getId())
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Your Workout Mode time: 30sec", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            yogaDB.saveSettingMode(0);
        }
        else if(selectedID == rdiMedium.getId())
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Your Workout Mode time: 20sec", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            yogaDB.saveSettingMode(1);
        }
        if(selectedID == rdiHard.getId())
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Your Workout Mode time: 10sec", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            yogaDB.saveSettingMode(2);
        }
    }

    private void setRadioButton(int mode) {
        if(mode == 0)
            rdiGroup.check(R.id.rdioEasy);
        else if(mode == 1)
            rdiGroup.check(R.id.rdioMedium);
        else if(mode == 2)
            rdiGroup.check(R.id.rdioHard);
    }
}
```

.
.
..
.
.
.
.
...........................................................................................................

Comment: Hi! please edit your question with a clear description of what you meed help wit, and avoid unnecessary text/symbols (like all the dots at the end)

Comment: Use channel for notification as explained https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-o-how-to-use-notification-channels--cms-28616